# require not working on ruby 2.0?

Tags: ruby

I'm doing a test with "require" under  `ruby 2.0.0p576 (2014-09-19 revision 47628) [x86_64-darwin13.4.0]` it doesn't work in many ways.
  There are two files in ruby directory as shown below:

string_extensions.rb

```
class String
         def vowels
           self.scan(/[aeiou]/i)
         end
end
```

vowels_test.rb

```
require 'string_extensions'
   puts "This is a test".vowels.join('-')
```

fire up IRB

```
Snailwalkers-MacBook-Pro:ruby snailwalker$  ruby vowels_test.rb

returs : `require': cannot load such file -- string_extensions (LoadError)
```

I tried to change require 'string_extensions' to " `require_relative 'string_extensions'` ; `require './string_extensions.rb'` . They all didn't work.

both return error :  `vowels_test.rb:1:in require_relative': /Users/snailwalker/Ruby/string_extensions.rb:1: class/module name must be CONSTANT (SyntaxError)`

Your help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you get the error `class/module name must be CONSTANT (SyntaxError)`, then there is a problem with your code, not with `require`.

Comment: From the last paragraph of your question, it is clear that the require is working but there is an error on line 1 of the file you are requiring.  Are you sure you posted the exact contents of that file here, with no typos?

Comment: Thank you guys so much . I found the issue, I didn't capitalize "class string" it should be " class String"  with a capitalised "S"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
ruby -I. vowels_test.rb
```

Automatic inclusion of the current directory in the load paths was removed in Ruby 2.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `require_relative` instead:

```
require_relative 'string_extensions'
puts "This is a test".vowels.join('-')
```

Or even `require './string_extensions'`.